# How to customize field names in Django admin change list only?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model with many boolean flags. Some of them are displayed in admin change list and made editable by `list_editable` - this makes them appear as checkboxes. The problem is that this wastes a lot of horizontal space as field names are long (and I want to keep them descriptive for model change form). For regular fields I use custom properties and `short_description` to shorten the name. But in that case I have to render checkbox but I do not know how to make it properly.

Or may be there is another hack to alter field name for change list only?

Comment: https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/django-admin-cookbook/latest/django-admin-cookbook.pdf

Comment: @MohitHarshan how this document is supposed to help me? Speaking in context of this document (chapter 7) I want "is immortal" and "is very benevolent" to be very short but only on listview page.

Answer (score -1):

If I got you right, the `verbose_name` model attribute is what you're looking for.

```
new_tab = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='n_tab')
```

This way `new_tab` field will appear as `n_tab` in admin interface. You can set `verbose_name` to empty string too.

Comment: I know how to name fields. What I want is to show different names on the list view and change view.